TL494 - Darlington circuit
Below is an example diagram from the TL494 datasheet.
The maximum collector current of TL494 is 250 mA.
There is a calculation of the base current and R10 base resistance for Q1 (pnp) using the hfe values ​​of the transistors. I understood the calculations in the datasheet, there is no problem, but my questions are as follows:

The base current for Q1 was selected as 144 mA. When TL494 is on,
the current will flow through R11 (pull up resistor) and R10 from 32V, isn't it?
The collector current seems sum of base current flowing from Q1
(pnp) to the collector of TL494 and a current flowing through R11 +
R10 while on? If so, how can I calculate the maximum current flowing
from the collector of TL494?
When TL494 is on, doesn't it seem like there is a voltage divider
between R11 and R10 for Q1? if so this will affect the base of Q1 ?


Source : https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf?ts=1724096362175&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

This is a Sziklai pair, not a Darlington.

@Hearth They called it a hybrid Darlington so they are creating their own term. It's not so good to have done that here, of course, because it might just as well be one of these. Who knows? But I'm sure the author would use hybrid as an escape clause against your criticism. ;) The OP is excused, though. They were just copying and pasting without knowing any different.

The B-E junction of Q1 limits the voltage across R11 to about 0.7 V, which limits the current through R11 to about 7 mA. All of the rest of the current through R10 flows through Q1. Nearly all of the supply voltage appears across R10, so the total current is determined by its value. ~30 V / 270 Ω gives about 110 mA. Subtracting the R11 current leaves about 100 mA flowing through Q1's base. I'm not sure what happened to the target current of 144 mA. It looks like there was a transposition of digits in the schematic. The calculated 207 became 270.

I got it, so 32V - 0.7 V = 31.3 V at the base of Q1 which means (32V - 31.3V) / 100 ohm=  7mA through R11. In this case I have another question sir, for pnp transistors the conditions is  VE> VB . In our case VE =32 V and VB= 31.3 V means VE is slightly higher than VB so it seems it is not a proper conduction for Q1, isn't it ?
@Dave Tweed

No, it's perfectly proper. As we calculated, there's at least 100 mA of base current for Q1, which is plenty. If R10 is reduced to 200 Ω, then that base current rises to the intended 144 mA.

You should simulate this circuit.
Here is an example, made with microcap v12.
I don't own this power BJT in my database, replaced by some others.
Currents through R17 and R18 are "small" compared with relative Ib(Q1) and Ib(Q2).

